# Avoid wake up on collision

Tags: javascript, cannon.js

I'm working with [cannon-es](https://pmndrs.github.io/cannon-es/docs/index.html) (a maintained fork of cannon.js). I need to fix an object in space for a certain period of time. So, I do `body.sleep()` in these cases.

The problem is that object can collision with other object and it wakes up. So I add `body.collisionResponse = 0` but it doesn't work. body becomes a ghost object (no response to collision) but still wake up on collision.

Is there a way to avoid wake up on collision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [collisionfiltergroup](https://pmndrs.github.io/cannon-es/docs/classes/body.html#collisionfiltergroup)  and [collisionFilterMask](https://pmndrs.github.io/cannon-es/docs/classes/body.html#collisionfiltermask) properties.

[Here an example of use.](https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js/blob/master/demos/collisionFilter.html)

So, in the body creation:

```js
const body = new CANNON.Body({
    mass: 1,
    shape: shape,
    material: this.physicsWorld.defaultMaterial,
    collisionFilterGroup: 1,
    collisionFilterMask: 1
})
```

And, when it has to get fixed:

```
body.sleep()
body.collisionFilterMask = 2
```